# Creating a Corpus using tm package in R

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I created a character vector from some mined tweets using the code

```
tweets_text <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText(x))
```

I tried creating a corpus from the character vector source using the code

```
my_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets_text)
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Error in as. vector(x, "character"):
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

The `dput(head(tweets))` for one of the tweets returned as

```
structure(function () 
    text, mayCall = character(0), name = "getText", refClassName = "status", superClassMethod = "", class = structure("refMethodDef", package = "methods")))` and str(tweets) is ` $ :Formal class 'refMethodDef' [package "methods"] with 5 slots
  .. ..@ .Data           :function ()  
  .. ..@ mayCall         : chr(0) 
  .. ..@ name            : chr "getText"
  .. ..@ refClassName    : chr "status"
  .. ..@ superClassMethod: chr ""
```

Comment: is `tweets_text` actually a character vector?  I think `x$getText(x)` should be just `getText(x)` ?

Comment: Show us `dput(head(tweets))`. Apparently it's not a character vector like you expected...

Comment: when I tested for the structure of the tweets, the result for one of the tweets was given as `$ :Formal class 'refMethodDef' [package "methods"] with 5 slots
  .. ..@ .Data           :function ()  
  .. ..@ mayCall         : chr(0) 
  .. ..@ name            : chr "getText"
  .. ..@ refClassName    : chr "status"
  .. ..@ superClassMethod: chr ""`

Comment: @SymbolixAU I will try using `getText(x)` and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: @smci `dput(head(tweets))` for one of the tweets is given as `list(structure(function () 
text, mayCall = character(0), name = "getText", refClassName = "status", superClassMethod = "", class = structure("refMethodDef", package = "methods")), 
    structure(function ()`

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `dput(head(tweets))`, rather than including it in a comment.

Comment: Also include `str(tweets)`.